# unable to work with if/else in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to execute this query:

```
$sl="update customers set activation_code='$reg' WHERE  c_number='$users1' and password='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sl);
if (mysql_error()) {
    ?>
    <script type=text/javascript>
       window.alert("Error, You have not used our services before, so no details for you to visit and explore");
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    echo $reg;
}
```

everytime i enter the details i get the the activation key being displayed... means it os not picking at all my if clause.... please help me to resolve this
help me how to to resolve this

Comment: For future reference (at least while developing) it's a good idea to display the actual SQL error message, and post it here on SO when you need help like this. That message would have told you exactly where in the SQL statement your problem was

Comment: Also, please stop using the MySQL extension because it is subject to SQL Injection, and is now deprecated in PHP; and learn to use prepared statements with the MySQLi or PDO extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You have use WHERE clause two time it should be

```
$sl="update customers set activation_code='$reg' WHERE  c_number='$users1' and password='$id'"
```

Comment: you mean: "update customers set activation_code='$reg' WHERE  c_number='$users1' and password='$id'" ?

Comment: please chceck my edited question ... i hv done what u have said.. but now my error is : its not picking 'if' clause at all

Comment: @MaryamButt : for that you have to check $result variable returns by mysql_query();

Comment: i hv chcked that also but no result... still problm sustains

Comment: @MaryamButt : check for $result if it is true then row is updated otherwise not. you can also print that query and execute in mysql(phpmyadmin) and find what is wrong with query..